# Why can't PHP create a file, even with 777 permissions?

Tags: php, xampp, file-permissions, archlinux

I have a virtual Arch Linux test server with XAMPP running on my laptop, and I can't get php to create new files, even with permissions set at 777. Here's the code:

```
$CompleteFilepath = $AFilepath . '/filepath/filename.php';
$FileHandle = fopen($CompleteFilepath, 'c')
    or
die ("cannot be opened for writing"); // Debug
```

There's obviously more code after, but it's irrelevant because it always dies here. I couldn't get it to work by modifying the owner and group settings, so I finally resorted to recursively setting everything (except for the main root folder) to 777, and it still won't work. But the folder isn't being created directly in the root, so it shouldn't matter, right?

Edit:
I'm still not really sure what I was doing wrong, but today I set the owner to the server and it worked. I thought I had tried that, but maybe not. At least I can get on with development, even if I need to configure my production server more securely in the end.

Comment: Whats the error log say?

Comment: Print the complete file path in the error message. And yes, `777` on the containing folder ought to be enough.

Comment: which error log? php? It doesn't seem to be adding any error to the php error log.
JakeGould, $CompleteFilepath is a new filepath, where $AFilepath is a pre-existing filepath, and is NOT the root directory.
mario, When I print the complete filepath, it is the correct filepath.

Comment: It only gives 200 and 300 'errors' in the access log, although in the "test" folder, where this script resides, it gives '"...HTTP/1.1" 200 2686' and on the script itself, it gives '"...HTTP/1.1" 200 2574' Not sure what the 4-digit ones mean. There's no entry for the folder in which the new directory is supposed to be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has a directive named [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) which permit to limit the access on filesystem to specified directory-tree.

For example if you have in your `php.ini`:

```
open_basedir = /srv/http/:/home/:/tmp/
```

and you will access the file `/filepath/filename.php`, then you must set:

```
open_basedir = /srv/http/:/home/:/tmp/:/filepath/
```

otherwise PHP will not be able to access the file.

In this way that will allow **all** PHP code running on this machine to access `/filepath/`  directory-tree, so it is **not secure** for production environment. The better way is to set *virtual-host* based `open_basedir` in `httpd.conf`. I let you check your HTTP server documentation and also [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) documentation for that.

Comment: Thanks. I already rewrote the code for production (it now uses mod_rewrite) but this is what I was looking for when I asked the question.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with a clean install of CentOS 7. It turned out it had SELinux installed by default, which was preventing all PHP writes, even when directory permissions were correct.

Test if SELinux is installed: `sestatus`

Put SELinux in permissive mode: `setenforce 0`

Comment: after 3 years u made my day, easy answer but i waqs looking for it for day and half ...

Answer (score 0):

what php version is running, afaik option 'c' is only available with php 5.2.6 and up.

or short: does

```
$FileHandle = fopen($CompleteFilepath, 'w');
```

work?

Comment: I'm running 5.4.7, so this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I set the owner to the server and now it works. I thought I had tried that already, but apparently not. Still not sure exactly what I was doing wrong but at least now it works so I can get on with development.